# Sql server real datatype, what is the C# equivalent?

Tags: c#, sql-server

What is the C# equivalent to the sql server 2005 real type?

Comment: Voted down because this answer is flawless and it has been on here for 13 days.

Comment: Is there a way for the community to accept answers to abandoned questions, other than merely voting for them?

Answer (score 83):

it is a Single

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) for more info on SQL Server to .Net DataTypes

Comment: Why was this answer not accepted? This is not how the community should be working. Too many questions are going weeks with no accepted answer.

Comment: Who cares?  The author didn't care to bother, but we as the community don't need their blessing to see and influence the "best" answer.

Comment: Single looses precision. Double should be a more appropriate candidate.

Comment: However I used always double due to precision minor issues. It's correct Single is the exact one but I had some problems with that type.

Comment: This is an old question, but as a fun fact the EF 6.0 Model-First generator generates a SQL column of type `real` when you select `Single` as the .NET type

Comment: Visual Studio 2105 wants to simplify 'Single' into 'float'

Comment: It is implementation-dependent (ie you need to check with each SQL version).  The implementation in SQL Server 2012+ is IEEE 754 compliant except for lack of support for constants NaN and +/- Infinity. If all you want is to be able to store a massively large number and do not mind all the rounding and precision baggage that the double precision data type (officially declared as DOUBLE PRECISION, FLOAT(53), or just FLOAT) brings with it then you should be OK.

Comment: I tried using Single, but ReSharper suggested using float instead.

Comment: @Rich `float` *is* `Single`. Same as `int` being `Int32` or `long` being `Int64`, it's just a shorthand alias.

Answer (score 10):

Single is not the correct answer as it rounds the  decimal part.. For instance 2.0799999
 will be  converted to 2.08. If there are no constraints regarding the rounding then it should be good.

Answer (score 7):

Double can be used as the .NET Equivalent Datatype for Real Datatype of SQL Server

Double gets the exact value with out Rounding

Comment: The correct type for double data type in .NET Framework  is float, you probably may get an excepction in execution time as I'm having at this moment.

Comment: @Leonardo - a C# struct 'System.Double' is the same as the intrinsic type 'double', not float as your comment suggests.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is Single. If you use double and your SQL field is type real it will error out. I tested this myself and confirmed.

Comment: float in C# = Single, it's just a synonym (like bool and Boolean)

Answer (score 3):

Its Equivalent is **Single**. 
Single is A floating point number within the range of -3.40E +38 through 3.40E +38.

[Here is the latest from MSDN describes all SqlDbType and C# Equivalents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/wf35eysz(v=VS.100,d=hv.2).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

the answer is `Single` *or* `float`. (depending on style.) 
this is like the difference between `String` and `string` [source: ReSharper code suggestion "use type keyword" when using `Single`. it suggested using `float`.

Answer (score 1):

in my project (acces -> firebird and ms sql -> c#) is real defined like single precission float point number...so I used float and everything is OK